# assert is failing for rapidJson

Tags: c++, rapidjson

I am trying to parse json data in c++ using RapidJson. I dont know where am I doing wrong but my assert is failing. When I try to debug its showing sigabrt when it runs the line assert. Community I appreciate your insights. Thanks for answering this naive question.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>
#include "hpdf.h"
#include "rapidjson/document.h"
#include "rapidjson/writer.h"
#include <rapidjson/istreamwrapper.h>
#include <fstream>

int main() {

    std::ifstream ifs("/home/is/..../test.json");
    rapidjson::IStreamWrapper isw(ifs);

    rapidjson::Document document;
    document.ParseStream(isw);


    assert(document.IsObject());

    rapidjson::Value::MemberIterator hello = document.FindMember("timeStamp");
    std::string vali = document["timestamp"].GetString();
    std::cout << vali << std::endl;

    return 0;

}
```

I tried using rapidJson filestream also but again it failed in the same line.

```
[
  {
    "timeStamp": "...",
    "alertType": "...",
    "instanceId": 8

   }
  ]
```

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info: `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). **Use the debugger** `gdb`. Check validity of JSON input, perhaps with [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/). Pass the input file path as a program argument to `main`

Comment: Read more carefully [RapidJson tutorial](http://rapidjson.org/md_doc_tutorial.html) then dive into the reference documentation

Comment: Lots of opportunity for error checking here. Maybe the file wasn't even opened.

Comment: You don't show your JSON data file (it could be wrong).

Comment: I'll check it. Thanks :D

Comment: Why do you compute `hello` without using it? Why don't you use `auto` for C++11 ?

Comment: I'm entering the json file also. Thanks guys. I appreciate your effort

Comment: Take time to read some good [C++ programming](http://stroustrup.com/Programming/) book. Read some [C++ reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) about every standard thing (e.g.[std::ifstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream)) you are using.

Comment: @Bijju: remember, SO is not a do-my-homework service. Read also http://norvig.com/21-days.html; you did not spend enough time on debugging your program and issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read more about [JSON](http://json.org/).

Your input document (starting with a `[`) is a JSON array containing a single JSON object.

I recommend using [`document.GetType()`](http://rapidjson.org/classrapidjson_1_1_generic_value.html) then have different processing on its result (perhaps with a `switch`).

So it is normal that `document.IsObject()` is false. For your input `document.IsArray()` should be true and your JSON object inside that array is accessible thru `document[0]`

Comment: JsonObject in rapidjson considers arrays also as a JsonObject

Comment: What's the difference between `IsArray()` and `IsObject()` then?

Answer (score 1):

99% on that your JSON is wrong.

Yet, `"timeStamp"` is not the same as `"timestamp"`

Comment: Yeah the time stamp in the json data is timeStamp. The problem is it doesn't even reach till that point. It stops before that line.

Answer (score 0):

Guys I think I have fixed the problem. You guys are right from the starting. There is a problem with my data.json. This library works when there is no [] in the .json file. I removed the square brackets and everything seems to work fine. Thank you for your time and insights. I appreciate all of your responses.

Comment: this is not an answer